# How to access hosted Beanstalkd server

Tags: node.js, beanstalkd

Beginner in Beanstalkd here. I have a hosted Beanstalkd server elsewhere with the following URL : http://beanstalkdhost:1234/here.

Questions:
- How would I be able to view the lists of tubes/jobs available? Note that this server is not hosted by me.

- How do I put jobs into the tubes of this server, when specs says it requires a POST and custom headers for a request. The clients (in NodeJS) I have came across over the Internet at the moment, do not allow for custom headers, and also almost always requires a 'port number' parameter which messes up the whole URL. It will end up as 'http://beanstalkdhost:1234/here:1234'.

Do note that I am also running a Windows machine (I believe there might be some limitations).

Will appreciate if I can get some advice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Beanstalkd is not a webservice. It does not present as a web-URL, but as a TCP socket that a connection is opened to, and bytes are sent to.

Knowing who is running the server for you might help out a lot in assisting you, but it does not appear to be a standard Beanstalkd queue.